# Unhandled Exception : 0x80000002: Datatype misalignment while using dynamic_cast on Win CE

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I have a C++ application written for Win 32 platform. I am porting this code to support Windows CE for platform ARMV4I.

On below line it throws exception of "0x80000002: Datatype misalignment":

```
RemotePlatformImpl* platform = dynamic_cast<RemotePlatformImpl*>(&handle);
```

Here type of handle is PlatformHandle but actually it points to RemotePlatformImpl object. RemotePlatformImpl is child class of PlatformHandle.

Following is the assembly code from VS2005 debugger:

```
RemotePlatformImpl* platform = dynamic_cast<RemotePlatformImpl*>(&handle);
421C4F34    ldr     r3, [pc, #0x464]
421C4F38    ldr     r2, [pc, #0x45C]
421C4F3C    mov     lr, #1
421C4F40    mov     rl, #0
421C4F44    mov     r0, r8
421C4F48    str     lr, [sp]
421C4F4C    bl      421D9970
```

Please let me if any additional information is required.

Minimal Code to duplicate issue:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class PlatformHandle
{
public:
    virtual ~PlatformHandle(){}

    bool operator==(const PlatformHandle& that) const { return (this == &that); }

    bool operator!=(const PlatformHandle& that) const { return !(this == &that); }

    PlatformHandle(){}
};

class RemotePlatformImpl : public PlatformHandle
{
public:
    virtual ~RemotePlatformImpl(){}
    RemotePlatformImpl(string srvAddr, int ctrlPort, int dataPort): PlatformHandle(){}
};

void justTest( PlatformHandle& handle)
{
    PlatformHandle& platform = dynamic_cast<RemotePlatformImpl&>(handle);
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PlatformHandle* ph = new RemotePlatformImpl("",2020,2021);
    justTest( *ph );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The additional information needed is a complete, minimal example to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: It would require lot of efforts as it depends on so many other classes. Though let me see if I can do it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to cast `&handle` rather than `handle`?

Comment: That was a try I gave. Before it was RemotePlatformImpl& platform = dynamic_cast<RemotePlatformImpl&>(handle); where type of handle is PlatformHandle&.

Comment: @Flexo: added minimal example code to reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by enabling switch in VS2005 project settings :

```
Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Enable Run-Time Type Info
```